# SQL query with string variable

Tags: sql, variables, jstl

I am trying to use this sql query but I need to replace the 'username' with a String variable!!

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result1">
SELECT name, code, price, quantity1, sub from basket where username = 'username';
</sql:query>
```

I am using mysql language in jsp...in the part of html

Any help is much appreciated:)

Comment: What language are you using with SQL?

Comment: but are you using mysql in java or PHP or...?

Comment: i am using it in jsp....but this part is in html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, code, price, quantity1, sub from basket where username = ? <sql:param value="${username}"/>
```

Comment: hi where shall i store the variable "username" as i am storing it in a string variabe in the java part and this code is not finding the variable

Comment: this is how i am storing it: String username = (String) session.getAttribute("userid");

Comment: this is how you should intialize your variable: <%! String username = ""; %>

Comment: and if you want to change it, you should do this: <% username = "john smith"; %>